# Best way to display percentages in Sweave?

Tags: formatting, sweave

What is the best way to display percentages in Sweave?

A simple example:

```
The number 4 is \Sexpr{4 / 7} of 7.
```

What is the best way to get the document to display:

> The number 4 is 57.1% of 7.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use `siunitx` for typesetting the number with the percent sign, which will take care of the correct spacing, and do the conversion to a percentage and the rounding within the `\Sexpr`:

```
The number 4 is \SI{ \Sexpr{round(4 / 7 * 100, 1)} }{\percent} of 7.
```

Comment: That's perfect.  All the other ways I tried seemed like too much of a hack.  Thank you!